# Why are Deeplinks from browser not working?

Tags: ionic4, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, deeplink, android-deep-link

I've implemented deeplinking in my ionic 4 app and everything works fine with:

1. URL Scheme links from the browser, e.g. "myapp://home"
2. Universal links when called using ADB command, e.g. adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://mywesbite.com/home" com.mybundleid.com

However, it does NOT work when clicking a Universal link from the browser directly, e.g. "https://mywesbite.com/home"

I have my assetlinks.json and apple-app-association files set up and on the domain.

What am I missing?

Please help!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution, this is exactly where I am running into as well. ADB works without an issue but tapping on a link in an email or message not.

Comment: Nope... never did. Pretty frustrating. You would think someone would have found a work around solution of some kind but I just went in a different direction with this.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've setup a new question which more tailored to my situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956993/deeplinks-work-with-adb-but-not-when-tapping-links-in-email-or-message-app Hope someone figured this out