# Deeplinks work with ADB but not when tapping links in email or message app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, deep-linking, ionic-native

My `AndroidManifest.xml` contains:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="books.com" android:pathPrefix="/book" />
</intent-filter>
```

And it is opening my app with the correct page when running

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://books.com/book/my-book-123" -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE
```

or

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://books.com/book/my-book-123" com.books.app
```

When I send https://books.com/book/my-book-123 via email or message app, it just opens the browser when I tap it.

If I remove `android:pathPrefix="/book"` it works, but then every url will open the app while I only want to open the `books.com/books` urls

I've checked that in my phone that books.com does not have set the "always open" set to my browser.

Comment: It is looking good. Have you tried removing the  `android:pathPrefix`?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Yes, when I do it works (I'll update my question to note this as well). The issue is that it then matches every link on books.com while I only want to match books.com/book and keep the others opening in the browser

Comment: Can you try this link? `https://books.com/book?my-book=123` and if it is opening the app?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun `https://books.com/book` prompts to open in app or browser, `https://books.com/book?my-book=123` opens directly in the browser

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links), Web links are deep links that use the HTTP and HTTPS schemes. On Android 12 and higher, **clicking a web link (that is not an Android App Link) always shows content in a web browser**. On devices running previous versions of Android, if your app or other apps installed on a user's device can also handle the web link, users might not go directly to the browser. Instead, they'll see a disambiguation dialog.

Android App Links
Android App Links, available on Android 6.0 (API level 23) and higher, are web links that use the HTTP and HTTPS schemes and contain the autoVerify attribute. This attribute allows your app to designate itself as the default handler of a given type of link. So when the user clicks on an Android App Link, your app opens immediately if it's installed—the disambiguation dialog doesn't appear.

So in a few words, you have to prove that you own that domain to be able to do what you´re trying to do, otherwise the web browser will load the URL.